# a weakening of full subcategories

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory, terminology

Is there a name for the following notion in category theory, which weakens fullness?

A subcategory $\mathcal A$ of $\mathcal B$ has the property that for all objects $x,y \in \mathcal A$, if there is an arrow $f : x \to y$ in $\mathcal B$ then there is one in $\mathcal A$ also.

Bump: I have chosen the name *honest* subcategory. Why is this an interesting notion?  Consider a small category $\mathcal C$ which is in some level of the set-theoretic hierarchy $V_\alpha$.  Let $M \prec V_\alpha$ be an elementary submodel with $\mathcal C \in M$.  Then $\mathcal C \cap M$ is an honest subcategory of $\mathcal C$, but not necessarily full.  The point is that honesty is witnessed by first-order properties, while fullness is not.

Comment: I haven't encountered any name for it, but you may speculate with terminology like "subcategory with the preordered reflection wich is a subpreorder".

Comment: A quick comment: the example you give of course has much stronger reflection properties - e.g. that every finite diagram consisting only of objects/arrows in $\mathcal{A}$ which has a limit or colimit in $\mathcal{B}$, has that same limit or colimit in $\mathcal{A}$. Do you have any motivating examples of honest subcategories which fail to have such properties?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not really. Does this stronger notion of preserving limits and colimits have a concise name?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Does your notion imply honesty? Consider a subcategory of two distinct objects and no arrows from one to the other. If there is an arrow in the larger category, does this violate your property?

Comment: @mbsq "Does this stronger notion of preserving limits and colimits have a concise name?" Not to my knowledge. "Does your notion imply honesty?" I don't think so - I was considering it in addition to honesty. My instinct was just that it seemed to capture "finite elementarity" in some sense.